# Can you disable ctrl-mousewheel to zoom in microsoft visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I have ctrl-mouse wheel bound to scroll in autohotkey. Id like to disable it in  Microsoft visual studio. Any idea how?
Thanks!

Comment: There is an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NoahRichards.DisableMouseWheelZoom) available, which supports VS2012 upto VS2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to disable mouse wheel in Visual Studio.

However a couple of extensions have been developed that provide this.

The original which supports VS2013 to VS2019 can be found either through the Visual Studio Manage Extension window. Or download directly from the [Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NoahRichards.DisableMouseWheelZoom)

And a version for VS2022 is available on GitHub, [DisableMouseWheelZoom for VS2022](https://github.com/MvRens/DisableMouseWheelZoom)